# Retrival of synced data

Tags: 8.0, backup, nokia-lumia-720

I bought a Nokia Lumia 720 couple of days back. I stored some data in it and also synced (Onenotes, contacts & apps) with the Hotmail account. Now if I restore my phone, is it possible to retrieve my contacts, Onenotes, apps etc from that Hotmail account? If it is possible, then what is the procedure to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all you'd need do is sign in with the same Hotmail account when setting the phone up again - you can also use this to transfer contacts, and calendar appointments between different versions of Windows Phone, for example, if you previously had a Lumia 500 running Windows Phone 7.5.